# Cannot display the other copy of ImageIcons when button pressed in memory game in Java

Tags: java, button, imageicon

I'm making a memory card game in java it consists of 10 ImageIcons the first 5 ImageIcons are the original ones and the other 5 are copies and I cannot find a way to display the other side of the other images copied when the button is pressed, I made a for loop in order to make 2 copies of the images and made them have the same index but the buttons works only on the first  5 ImageIcons but it doesn't work on the other 5 copies of the ImageIcons  (although they have the same index)

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class MemoControl extends JFrame{


            JPanel game;
            EventClass event;
            private JButton button[];
            private JLabel label[];
            private ImageIcon image[];
            private ImageIcon flippedImg;
            private String imgNames[];//not used yet
            int num;

            public MemoControl(){


                    setTitle("MyMemo Game");
                    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

                    game = new JPanel();
                    image = new ImageIcon[50];
                    button = new JButton[50];
                    label = new JLabel[50];

                    flippedImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("card_cover1.jpg"));;
                    for(int j = 1; j<6; j++)
                    {
                        image[j] =  new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(j+".jpg"));
                        button[j] = new JButton("");
                        button[j].addActionListener(new MemoControl.EventClass());
                        button[j].setIcon(flippedImg);
                        add(button[j]);

                        image[j] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(j+".jpg"));
                        button[j] = new JButton("");
                        button[j].addActionListener(new MemoControl.EventClass());
                        button[j].setIcon(flippedImg);
                        add(button[j]);

                        /*label[j] = new JLabel(image[j]);
                        add(label[j]);*/
                    }

                    EventClass event = new EventClass();

                    /*button = new JButton[50];
                    for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++)
                    {
                        button[i] = new JButton("");

                        add(button[i]);
                        button[i].addActionListener(event);
                    }*/

                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    pack();
                    setVisible(true);


                }//MyMemo constr end //event class

                private class   EventClass implements ActionListener {

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                            for (int i = 0; i <6; i++) {
                                if (e.getSource() == button[i]) {
                                    button[i].setIcon(image[i]);
                                }
                            }

                        }
    }

            public static void main(String args[]){

                    MemoControl gui = new MemoControl();
                    }//main end



}//AMYMemo class end
```

******************updated:

```
  import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;


public class MemoControl extends JFrame{


            JPanel game;
            EventClass event;
            private JButton button[][];
            private JLabel label[][];
            private ImageIcon image[][];
            private ImageIcon flippedImg;
            private String imgNames[];//not used yet
            int num;

            public MemoControl(){


                    setTitle("MyMemo Game");
                    setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));

                    game = new JPanel();
                    image = new ImageIcon[2][5];
                    button = new JButton[2][5];
                    label = new JLabel[2][5];

                    flippedImg = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("card_cover1.jpg"));;
                    for(int i = 0; i < image.length(); i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < image.length(); j++) {
                            image[i][j] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(j+".jpg"));
                            button[i][j] = new JButton("");
                            button[i][j].addActionListener(new MemoControl.EventClass());
                            button[i][j].setIcon(flippedImg);
                            add(button[i][j]);
                        }
}

                    EventClass event = new EventClass();

                    /*button = new JButton[50];
                    for(int i = 1; i<=5; i++)
                    {
                        button[i] = new JButton("");

                        add(button[i]);
                        button[i].addActionListener(event);
                    }*/

                    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                    pack();
                    setVisible(true);


                }//MyMemo constr end //event class

                private class   EventClass implements ActionListener {

                        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                            for(int i = 0; i < image.length(); i++) {
                        for(int j = 0; j < image[0].length(); j++) {
                                if (e.getSource() == button[i][j])
                                    button[i].setIcon(image[i][j]);
                            }
                            }

                        }
    }

            public static void main(String args[]){

                    MemoControl gui = new MemoControl();
                    }//main end

    }//AMYMemo class end
```

errors after update:

```
G:\MYMemo\MemoControl.java:31: error: cannot find symbol
                    for(int i = 0; i < image.length(); i++) {
                                            ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable image of type ImageIcon[][]
G:\MYMemo\MemoControl.java:32: error: cannot find symbol
                        for(int j = 0; j < image.length(); j++) {
                                                ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable image of type ImageIcon[][]
G:\MYMemo\MemoControl.java:64: error: cannot find symbol
                            for(int i = 0; i < image.length(); i++) {
                                                    ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: variable image of type ImageIcon[][]
G:\MYMemo\MemoControl.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
                        for(int j = 0; j < image[0].length(); j++) {
                                                   ^
  symbol:   method length()
  location: class ImageIcon[]
G:\MYMemo\MemoControl.java:67: error: cannot find symbol
                                    button[i].setIcon(image[i][j]);
                                             ^
  symbol:   method setIcon(ImageIcon)
  location: class JButton[]
5 errors
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of issues I see here, not all pertaining to the question.

First of all, `for(int j = 1; j<6; j++)` is going to loop 6 times. Inside the loop, you're running `add(button[j])` twice, which means it will add 12 items total, not 10.

Second of all, you're assigning `button[j]` twice per loop. This means you're overwriting the first value of `button[j]`. As an example, look at the following code:

```
int[] arr = new int[5];
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = 10
    arr[i] = 20
}
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print(arr[i] + ", ");
}
//20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
```

Notice these are all 20, and there are no 10s. So the reason you only have half your objects is because you're overwriting the initial half. You say "although they have the same index". An array is just a collection of objects. So `array[0]` is essentially `someVar`, and setting it to an object removes whatever it previously stored.

If what you're trying to do is have a 2x5 grid, then you should use a 2D array. In your case:

```
images = new ImageIcon[2][5];
buttons = new JButton[2][5];
labels = new JLabel[2][5];
```

Now, to iterate through, you would do

```
for(int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < images[0].length(); j++) {
        images[i][j] = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(j+".jpg"));
        buttons[i][j] = new JButton("");
        button[i][j].addActionListener(new MemoControl.EventClass());
        button[j].setIcon(flippedImg);
        add(button[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Now, I don't understand the overall structure of your program, but the above would create 10 buttons, where the `ImageIcon` matches between rows. Ex. `button[0][0]`'s image would be the same as `button[1][0]`'s image.

Hopefully I explained that relatively clearly. My java's a little rusty, so there might be some syntax errors.

Comment: the program is memory card game where you have to find the all pairs of cards that match in order to win, that's why I want to make another copy of every image and there are only one copy of every card.

Comment: Yes, I gathered that much.

Comment: Still doesn't work or can't figure out how to do it.sorry, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: Did you change your `actionPerformed` method to account for the 2D array?

Comment: yes, but keep saying cannot find symbol in all images.length.

Comment: Can you update your original question with the new errors and information please.

Comment: Okay, array `length`s are variables. Remove the brackets, that was my mistake.